# React class module doesn't build class correctly

Tags: reactjs

I use class modules throughout my project, but for some reason in one of my components it isn't built correctly:

```
import Body from './Body';
import IllustrationJobs from '../../assets/images/illu_jobs.svg';

import styles from "./Careers.modules.css";

const Careers = () => {
    return (
        <Body>
            <section className={styles.rowOneContainer}>
                <div className={`${styles.careersText} animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft`}>Right now we don't have any open positions. Make sure to check by
                soon again or contact us directly.</div>
                <div className={`${styles.careersImage} animate__animated animate__fadeInRight`}><img src={IllustrationJobs} alt="illustration_jobs"/></div>
            </section>
        </Body>
    )
}
export default Careers;
```

CSS

```
.rowOneContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.careersText {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: var(--salaryx-purple-dark);
}

.careersImage {
    width: 50%;
}
```

returns

[image]

[image]

while in other components the very same syntax returns the correct `class`. Why's that?

Comment: Could you share the folder structure you have?

Comment: Where have you imported Body in this file?

Comment: @AdityaRastogi it is imported, typo in my code snipper above

Comment: Do you have the codebase up on github on somewhere I could have a look, I think maybe the contents of body are causing this issue, the code directly works fine on my local as well

Comment: @AdityaRastogi thanks, I just pushed it to GitHub: https://github.com/Jonas-SRB/salaryx

Comment: I think you forgot to push the code

Comment: @AdityaRastogi now - sorry! https://github.com/Jonas-SRB/salaryx

Comment: It's supposed to be careers.module.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careers.modules.css is invalid format for the file
Use Careers.module.css instead

Answer (score 0):

What is the "animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft"?.

1. Is that a style module or regular CSS?
2. Are those two class names?
3. Where is the code for this?

Comment: Please post this as a comment as this is not an answer to the question

Comment: I can't duo to reputation level. I can comment on my own.
Before I also wrote about the Body component. Someone else wrote it so I edited it because there is no need to annoy  & poke people. :)